# How to use kotlin flow flatMap in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow

In my application I want **flatMap** operators such as `flatMapMerge`.
But after write codes show me **highlight** on `flatMapMerge` and say add one annotation!
**I write below codes :**

```
    private fun myFunction() {
    lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated {
        flowOf("Nerd", "Subby", "Mord")
            .flatMapMerge { userInfo(it) }
            .collect {
                binding.showInfoText.append("$it \n")
            }
    }
}
```

**Show me below highlight :**
[image]

When added this annotation : `@FlowPreview` , then not show this highlight!
But my question is why show this highlight? why I should add this annotation?
What's worked this annotation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**why show this highlight?**

Flow preview has no backward compatibility guarantees, including both binary and source compatibility

**why I should add this annotation?**

you are accept/agree on  the drawback of relying on preview API. In the document they are mentioned , they collecting the feed backs on this.upcoming release they will fix the issue.

refer [FlowPreview](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-flow-preview/index.html)